# Weird behavior when using custom HTTP header

Tags: php, html, ajax, http, http-headers

My website uses AJAX to load pages into a `div` and sends the following custom header with each AJAX request: `X-AJAXRequest`.

If the header is present my website sends the body without the header and footer, otherwise it sends the whole page.

This is my PHP code:

```
if ( !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_AJAXREQUEST']))
{
    echo($head);
    echo($body);
    echo($scripts);
}
else{
    include("master.php");
}
```

Now, the problem is, when someone visits X, clicks on Y's link then from Y click's on X, X is loaded with the header and footer as if the header doesn't exist. Even peculiar-er when developer tools (f12) are open this doesn't happen!

I think it might be caching, because IE11 (the browser I am developing with) has [Back Navigation Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn265017(v=vs.85).aspx), but even then, why would caching obliterate my header??

[Here's](http://cryptolight.cf) a link to the site that's having problems

Comment: Caching doesn’t interact with your header; caching means _no request is being sent at all_, and cached value is used. If with devtools opened it works, it’s definitely the caching problem. Set no-cache header in response.

Comment: Just to note, there is already a commonly used (although non-standard) header for ajax requests, its `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: @Flosculus I know, but I don't want to check the value of the header

Comment: Back navigation caching exists because the user is "going back" to see what was there previously.  It is over-ridable by forcing re-validation, if that is your only problem.  The question isn't very clear.  Additionally, links (`<a>`) don't have the facility to specify custom headers.  TBH you are far better off un-complicating things by using separate URLs.

Comment: We need to see the javascript then.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it is indeed caching that's causing you the trouble. Once the user has visited X, your browser caches it (based on whatever caching rules in has and the server provided). When you then go to Y and attempt to load X via AJAX, the browser knows that it already has X in the cache and delivers it from there (never sending a request to your server at all).

In Chrome, by default, caching is turned off when you open Developer Tools (F12) which is why you are not seeing this problem when you have them on. You can go into the Developer Tools Settings (upper right corner) and untick "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)". You should then be able to see the browser fetch X from cache on page Y.

One simple way to solve this is to also attach a parameter to the URL (something like "ajax=true" for example for ajax calls), this way the browser will treat X and X?ajax=true as two separate "resources" and cache two different versions of them.